# Browser won't launch on stopping docker

Tags: javascript, docker, jenkins, automation

I am new to docker concept. I have a  WebdriverIO automation framework repo on github running on Jenkins in a docker container on a windows machine.
I have updated "**services: ['chromedriver']**" in wdio.conf.js and stopped the docker on the windows machine.
When I run the build on Jenkins, I don't see a browser launching. What else do I need to update for a browser to launch
[image]
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance